# Oracle database unicode

Tags: oracle, unicode

Is there a way to define for a database to always use the Unicode that is defined in the database (regardless of the registry definition on the client side)?
I am looking for something like a hook that will always run and define the Unicode for the session.

(I know I can do it a batch file that I run before the scripts, but I want to do it automatically in the database before I run a script)

Comment: You should clarify what "the same Unicode" means, given that the sole purpose of Unicode is having a universal character catalogue. In any case, text encoding is a system-wide setting you decide when you install Oracle.

Comment: In any oracle database there is a configuration of unicode, "same Unicode" means the same Unicode as the oracle Unicode.

Comment: Oracle Unicode is the one from [Unicode Consortium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_Consortium). Are you talking about the values that show up when you run `SELECT * FROM NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS`?